# Need to change the caption using the javascript Facebook api to post to wall

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Facebook javascript to publish/post to user wall. HEre is my code below. Everytime user post to wall they get a screen like below. The problem is I am getting "www.facebook.com" in the caption after the Title text "Pandora-whichstar are you". Any idea how to either remove this permanently or change this to something more convenient?

**The image**

[image]

**The Code**

```
/facebook: post to wall 
function publishWallPost() {
      var fbImg = $('.head .headerLeft p img')[0].src;
      var fbTxt = $('.head .headRight span.artistName').text();
      FB.ui({
          method: 'feed',
          name: 'Pandora - Which Star Are You',
          caption: 'Convenient caption text here?',
          description: 'I\'m ' + fbTxt + ' according to Pandora\'s Which Star Are You competition.\n Click on the title to find out which star you are!',
          link: 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/xxx/11111111111?sk=app_2222222222',
          picture: fbImg
        },
        function (response) {
          console.log('publishStory response: ', response);
        });
      return false;
}


window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
      FB.init({
        appId: '2222222222',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
      });
};

(function () {
      var e = document.createElement('script');
      e.async = true;
      e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
      document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

Comment: Are you sharing the facebook page tab app?

Comment: yeep I am . I just want the caption text to say something else... better yet not to have the caption text at all

Comment: this is where I m having the issue . A js redirect is not feasible for this... http://on.fb.me/1hCfgOX

Comment: @Himu why not ? You can built a simple html page and drop it to dropbox. It's that simple? Is there any other issues?

Answer (score 2):

If Facebook is not letting you set the caption for a link on Facebook.com, what you can do instead is create a page that does a 301 redirect to the Facebook page you want to share and use that URL as the link parameter.

If a 301 redirect won't work, you can do a javascript redirect instead, but the same principle still applies.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like @Fisch told u. Build a site with an JS Redirect and use the OG Meta Tags.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Answer (score 2):

If u give caption or don't give caption, Facebook scraps URL.
By mandate,Facebook Domains URLs are not scraped.[Link 1](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages)
For URLs that cannot be scrapped mostly the caption is taken from Domain part.[For this is Facebook leave matter in users hands whether to go ahead with click or not.]

As Sahil, I am to afraid that "caption edit" is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

you can't give the Facebook page link on web dialogue.
you need to do what @Fisch and @Hackbard are telling you to do.

you need to give the link of some webpage that has following meta tags on it:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456789(your Facebook app id)" />
<meta property="og:title" content="X  Y  Z"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="game" /> (this depends upon your Facebook settings)
<meta property="og:url" content="www.yourWebpageLink.com/toPullOffDetails" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YOUR SITE NAME"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://the_image_you_want_to_show_on_that_dialogue"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="This is X Y Z, the best example on the planet" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Build a page with javascript redirect `window.location('url')` to your app page as others mentioned but you ***should not*** have to do something else. All of your configs look okay.

**Disclaimer: *Do not use* server side redirect as facebook will find out the URL you need to use *javascript* redirect as scrappers do not execute javascript.**

Answer (score 1):

While sharing a facebook link, facebook gives the relevant caption (sometimes description also) by itself.

If you try some link other than facebook, and give `caption` parameter you can see your caption in the feed. So, am afraid that you cannot edit the caption in your case.